# How to stop VS Code flagging TypeScript issues in JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

VS Code keeps trying to warn me about TypeScript errors in my JavaScript code. The project does have some TypeScript in other places, but not in this file.

Notice the white thing overlapping the `__`.

[image]

How can I stop it doing this?

I have tried these settings, which did not prevent it:

- `"typescript.validate.enable": false`
- `"vetur.validation.interpolation": false`

Basically, I don't want VS Code to do anything TypeScript-y in any `.js` file.

Comment: What the setting for allowJs in your TsConfig